# powershell pass .inf files to pnputil

Tags: powershell, driver, inf

I am trying to recursively search a directory, find any .inf files within and pass those files to pnputil to add those drivers to windows drivers directory.

I have the following:

```
cd /drivers

$x = ls -Path . -Filter "*.inf" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

Foreach ($i in $x){
     pnputil /a $i
}
```

and I get the following error from pnputil:

> Adding the driver package failed : Invalid INF passed as parameter.

I am assuming it's failing because pnputil doesn't like the object it's getting.  Any suggestion as to what to pass it, or what to modify?

Thank you!

Comment: `& pnputil /a $i.FullName` maybe.. im sure im close. You have a DirectoryInfo object. You just need to use the fullname property

Comment: Beautiful that is it exactly, Please post as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You knew what the issue was. You are passing an object to the command line. What you need to do is extract the full path from that `System.IO.FileInfo` object to pass to `pnputil`

```
Foreach ($i in $x){
    & pnputil /a $i.FullName
}
```

That should get you the results you are looking for. Another thing you could have done was change `$x` so that it was an array of file names. `-ExpandProperty` being the important part.

```
$x = ls -Path . -Filter "*.inf" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname

Foreach ($i in $x){
     pnputil /a $i
}
```

Comment: You're right, I think I was confusing myself as I was piping the object to select, `$i | select fullname` then to pnputil. Stupid thanks!